# Count occurrence within a group using different columns for each group

Tags: python, pandas

In df below there are three groups in the variable 'group' - 'A', 'AB', 'C'.
The other columns in the df is assigned to a specific group by suffix - var1_A relates to group A and so forth.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A', 'AB', 'A', 'AB', 'AB', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'AB'],
                     'var1_A':['pass', 'fail', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var2_A':['pass', 'pass', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var1_AB':['pass', 'pass', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var2_AB':['pass', 'pass', 'fail','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var1_C':['pass', 'pass', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var2_C': ['fail', 'fail', 'fail','fail', 'pass']*2
                    })
```

I want for each row count the number of times 'pass' occur. For the instances that belongs to group A I only want to count the variables that are connected to the group A. I want the result in a new column. This would almost do the job.

```
data['new_col'] = data[data['group']=='A']['var1_A, var2_A].isin(['pass']).sum(1)
data['new_col'] = data[data['group']=='AB']['var1_AB, var2_AB].isin(['pass']).sum(1)
data['new_col'] = data[data['group']=='C']['var1_C, var2_C].isin(['pass']).sum(1)
```

However, I want the result in the same column from all groups. This operation is perhaps possible to do using a groupby and transform? However, I got stuck figuring it out.

Target dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'group':['A', 'AB', 'A', 'AB', 'AB', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'AB'],
                     'var1_A':['pass', 'fail', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var2_A':['pass', 'pass', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var1_AB':['pass', 'pass', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var2_AB':['pass', 'pass', 'fail','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var1_C':['pass', 'pass', 'pass','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'var2_C': ['fail', 'fail', 'fail','fail', 'pass']*2,
                     'result':[2,2,2,0,2,1,1,2,0,2]
                    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), filter and [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```py
data['result'] = (data
  .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1]) # get only part after "_"
  .reset_index().melt(['index', 'group'])
  # keep only identical groups and "pass" values
  .loc[lambda d: d['group'].eq(d['variable']) & d['value'].eq('pass')]
  .groupby('index')['value'].count()
  .reindex(data.index, fill_value=0)
)

print(data)
```

Or another approach using matrices and string comparisons:

```
df2 = data.set_index('group').eq('pass')
data['result'] = (df2.mul(df2.columns.str.extract('_(\w+)', expand=False))
                     .eq(df2.index, axis=0).sum(axis=1)
                     .to_numpy()
                 )
```

Output:

```
  group var1_A var2_A var1_AB var2_AB var1_C var2_C  result
0     A   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       2
1    AB   fail   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       2
2     A   pass   pass    pass    fail   pass   fail       2
3    AB   fail   fail    fail    fail   fail   fail       0
4    AB   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   pass       2
5     C   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       1
6     C   fail   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       1
7     A   pass   pass    pass    fail   pass   fail       2
8     A   fail   fail    fail    fail   fail   fail       0
9    AB   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   pass       2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dd1=data.apply(lambda ss:data.filter(regex=".+_{}$".format(ss.group)).loc[ss.name].loc[lambda ss:ss.eq("pass")].count(),axis=1)
data["result"]=dd1
data
```

or pd.wide_to_long

```
dd1=pd.wide_to_long(data.assign(col1=data.index), stubnames=['var1','var2'],
                i=['col1'], j='col2',sep='_',suffix=r'\w+').reset_index()\
    .loc[lambda dd:dd.col2.eq(dd.group)].set_index("col1")
data.assign(result=dd1.var1.map({"pass":1}).add(dd1.var2.map({"pass":1}),fill_value=0).fillna(0))
```

out

```
  group var1_A var2_A var1_AB var2_AB var1_C var2_C  result
0     A   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       2
1    AB   fail   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       2
2     A   pass   pass    pass    fail   pass   fail       2
3    AB   fail   fail    fail    fail   fail   fail       0
4    AB   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   pass       2
5     C   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       1
6     C   fail   pass    pass    pass   pass   fail       1
7     A   pass   pass    pass    fail   pass   fail       2
8     A   fail   fail    fail    fail   fail   fail       0
9    AB   pass   pass    pass    pass   pass   pass       2
```